# How to upload image as public programmatically?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to upload an image in Google Cloud Storage as public automatically?

I tried this

**Code:**

```
func HandleFileUploadToBucket(c *gin.Context) {
    bucket := "mybucket"  

    var err error

    ctx := appengine.NewContext(c.Request)

    storageClient, err = storage.NewClient(ctx, option.WithCredentialsFile("keys.json"))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    f, uploadedFile, err := c.Request.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    defer f.Close()

    sw := storageClient.Bucket(bucket).Object(uploadedFile.Filename).NewWriter(ctx)

    sw.ACL = []storage.ACLRule{{Entity: storage.AllUsers, Role: storage.RoleReader}} // As you can see here I made it AllUser
    sw.CacheControl = "public, max-age=86400"

    if _, err := io.Copy(sw, f); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    if err := sw.Close(); err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    u, err := url.Parse("/" + bucket + "/user/" + sw.Attrs().Name)
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": err.Error(),
            "Error":   true,
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message":  "file uploaded successfully",
        "pathname": u.EscapedPath(),
    })
}
```

Here what happened
What I want 1st row
What I get 2nd row
**result:**

[image: pic]

Comment: does it work if you set it to `publicRead` https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists#predefined-acl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me in my code, separating the `upload file` and `setting the access privileges` actions. It would look something like this:

```
sw := storageClient.Bucket(bucket).Object(uploadedFile.Filename).NewWriter(ctx)

sw.CacheControl = "public, max-age=86400"

if _, err := io.Copy(sw, f); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
        "message": err.Error(),
        "error":   true,
    })
    return
}

if err := sw.Close(); err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
        "message": err.Error(),
        "error":   true,
    })
    return
}

//set public access
acl := storageClient.Bucket(bucket).Object(uploadedFile.Filename).ACL()
if err := acl.Set(ctx, storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader); err != nil {
   //handle error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the objects public after you upload them into the bucket. As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects) you can use something like the code below to make them public

```
func makePublic(w io.Writer, bucket, object string, entity storage.ACLEntity, role storage.ACLRole) error {
        // bucket := "bucket-name"
        // object := "object-name"
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("storage.NewClient: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*10)
        defer cancel()

        acl := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).ACL()
        if err := acl.Set(ctx, entity, role); err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("ACLHandle.Set: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Blob %v is now publicly accessible.\n", object)
        return nil
}
```